# Problem using Splide slider on mobile screens and flexbox layout on larger screens

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, splidejs

I'm using SplideJS as a slider, and in a redesign I want the slider only to be on mobile, and to use a flexbox layout on larger screens. Destroying the slider with breakpoints is easy enough, the problem is that Splide forces the `splide_list` element to have `display: block` when it is initialised, which then overrides the flex setting.

Since Splide forces the structure `track > list > slide`, the flex kind of has to be on the list element.

Even with `destroy: 'completely` it sets the following class:

```
.splide.is-initialized:not(.is-active) .splide__list {
    display: block;
}
```

This must be a fairly common scenario, to not being forced to have a block element holding all the items when destroying the slider?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried setting the slider to `destroy: true` and `destroy: 'completely'` with the breakpoint setting, and it destroys alright, but the CSS is still forcing the `splide_list` to be a block element. I would expect it not to set any specific `display` setting on this element once the slider is destroyed.